# Bootstrap dropdown css issue

Tags: dropdown

[image]

Bootstrap dropdown is working but css is not applied as expected.

Below are the list of .js and .css file included.[image]

Expected result is [image]

Comment: check your css files - whats happening is that you are getting the borders on the tds in the datepicker - you probably have some other style rule that is causing a conflict. Also you seem to be loading the full and the minified datetimepicker.css files - you only need one (usually the full one for dev and the min for production)

Comment: I included the js files in the header instead of footer. You can try that out.

Comment: it was site.css file causing the issue. Thanks gavgrif..

Comment: Thanks pooja..the issue is resolved..